# how to extract a part of char then compare it with another variable in C

Tags: c, char, compare, extract, signed

***so i want to extract a part of a char variable ,***
like
`signed char *a="06254148"`
*i want to extract "06" the first two characters
and compare it with "07"
i tried to use shift >> but i think it works only with integers !

*

```
int main ()
{
    signed char *a="021547";
    //int a=0x100201,b=0x102548;

    printf("%d", a>>12);
    return 0;
}
```

i know that what i have tried is false ;
*could someone help me please*

Comment: This is not a pointer to a char, but a pointer to a C-string.

Comment: @debanshudas could you please write the program,if it doesn't bother you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first character use:

```
a[0]
```

and for the second:

```
a[1]
```

and so on